# Rails Capistrano deploy says pg gem not found even though it's in the gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, capistrano

Hate to ask this question - it seems like it should be easier, but I'm stumped at this point... I am trying to do an initial install of a Rails app using Capistrano to a Digital Ocean droplet. This is a vanilla Rails app and runs fine on my local (Windows) machine with PG installed. However, when I run:

```
cap production deploy:initial
```

It starts to run but fails - buried in the middle is this message:

> rake stdout: rake aborted!
>   Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required

Now, the pg gem is in my gem file. When I run `bundle install` inside the release directory, the bundler runs just fine, but then when I run `bundle which`, pg is not present in the list.

> bundle list
>   Gems included by the bundle:
>     * actionmailer (4.1.8)
>     * actionpack (4.1.8)
>     * actionview (4.1.8)
>     * activemodel (4.1.8)
>     * activerecord (4.1.8)
>     * activesupport (4.1.8)
>     * arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
>     * autoprefixer-rails (6.3.6)
>     * babel-source (5.8.35)
>     * babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
>     * bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.2)
>     * builder (3.2.2)
>     * bundler (1.12.4)
>     * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
>     * coffee-script (2.4.1)
>     * coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
>     * connection_pool (2.2.0)
>     * erubis (2.7.0)
>     * execjs (2.6.0)
>     * hike (1.2.3)
>     * i18n (0.7.0)
>     * jbuilder (2.4.1)
>     * jquery-rails (3.1.2)
>     * json (1.8.3)
>     * mail (2.6.4)
>     * mime-types (3.0)
>     * mime-types-data (3.2016.0221)
>     * minitest (5.8.4)
>     * multi_json (1.12.0)
>     * puma (3.4.0)
>     * rack (1.5.5)
>     * rack-test (0.6.3)
>     * rails (4.1.8)
>     * railties (4.1.8)
>     * rake (11.1.2)
>     * rdoc (4.2.2)
>     * react-rails (1.7.1)
>     * sass (3.2.19)
>     * sass-rails (4.0.5)
>     * sdoc (0.4.1)
>     * sprockets (2.12.4)
>     * sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
>     * thor (0.19.1)
>     * thread_safe (0.3.5)
>     * tilt (1.4.1)
>     * turbolinks (2.5.3)
>     * tzinfo (1.2.2)
>     * uglifier (3.0.0)

I feel like this is something really simple but this is my first time doing a deploy of a Rails app and I've spent more hours than I care to admit trying to nail this down. I've also run `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config` as recommended on another SO answer and I've independently run `gem install pg`.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'

gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

gem 'react-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end

gem 'puma'

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what do you get when run `bundle show pg`?

Comment: "Could not find gem 'pg'. Did you mean pg?"

Comment: yes, when you run `bundle show [gem_name]` it will show you gem directory installed in your app , given you have run `bundle install` successfully. Can you remove pg gem and run bundle install again?

Comment: You mean run `gem uninstall pg` and then run `bundle install`? I went ahead and did that but it still is not picking up the pg gem - it's still absent from `bundle list` even though i can clearly see it in the Gemfile

Comment: hmm, weird, so what do you get when run this `gem list pg`?

Comment: It just shows "*** LOCAL GEMS ***" with nothing below it. One question - do I need to be running the bundle install as the same user that will access the database? It seems like that shouldn't matter just to install the gem successfully though.

Comment: haha, pg is not installed yet ;). running bundle is not related to database access though. I think the actual problem is something else. Ignoring bundle, if you run `gem install [gem_name]` successfully, then run `gem list [gem_name], it should show installed gem

Comment: did you mention running  `gem install pg` is fine?

Comment: Yep - when I run `gem install pg` and then `gem list pg` then it shows pg (0.18.4). But rake db:migrate still says pg isn't installed and cap still fails with the same error on deploy. Seems like it's swallowing an error somewhere..

Comment: another idea(just to test) is: remove pg again and delete Gemfile.lock from your project, then run `bundle install` again and watch the output. Any errors or warning this time?. Also you need to make sure postgresql is installed beforehand as well

Comment: Ah, now that's interesting. After doing that (uninstall, delete Gemfile.lock) and running `bundle install --no-deployment` it did install pg and then `bundle list` shows pg installed. I commit from local to github and then from local I run cap production deploy, which does a checkout on the server from github. So my lock file is in the repository - I thought that's how it was supposed to be, but it seems to be getting in the way now. So do I remove the lock file from git?

Comment: You don't have to remove lock file, bundle auto manages it. In your case, platform ie windows is the culprit :)

Answer (score 1):

Found it thanks to @kasperite's help!

In my local Gemfile.lock (on Windows, which was getting pushed to GitHub and then pulled for the deployment to the Ubuntu server) I had this line:

```
pg (0.18.4-x86-mingw32)
```

Once I changed that to:

```
pg (0.18.4)
```

And pushed to GitHub, it actually did do the install on the droplet and the deployment proceeded. (Got a different error, but that's progress.)

So, if you're developing on Windows with Rails+PG and deploying to Ubuntu (or anything not Windows, I assume), your lock file will have the Windows pg gem listed but you need the "vanilla" one.